# addTo* not setting back reference

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have 2 domains classes that have one-to-many relation:

```
class DataType {

    Integer id
    ...
    static hasMany = [dataTypeProps: DataTypeProp]
}

class DataTypeProp implements Serializable {

    String name
    String value
    static belongsTo = [dataType: DataType]

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        builder.append dataType.id
        builder.append name
        builder.toHashCode()
    }
}
```

Then I create a new `DataType` instance and add a property to it like this:

```
new DataType().
        addToDataTypeProps(name: 'test name', value: 'test value')
       .save()
```

I get a NullPointerException, because back reference to `DataType` was not yet set.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'id' on null object
    at de.marketmaker.dm.treasury.model.DataTypeProp.hashCode(DataTypeProp.groovy:13)
    at java_util_Set$add$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at Script1$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure4.doCall(Script1.groovy:22)
```

Gorm documentation says that back reference is set by addTo* methods. But the question is why it is called so late that it leads to exception.

Comment: What results do you see when you try `DataTypeProps dataProp = new DataTypeProps(name: 'test', value: 'test value'); dataProp.save(); new DataType().addToDataTypeProps(dataProp).save()`? Also, what version of Grails are you using?

Comment: I get `- Field error in object 'DataTypeProp' on field 'dataType': rejected value [null];` exception. I use 2.5.0 version

Answer (score 0):

I just did your same setup and had no problem! I can think of two things you should try though.

1) Change the property name *id* to something else, GORM gives you one of those for free. And,

2) The complaint is obvious, adding a child to a parent that is not settled in the database yet. So, declare and save the parent, and then add children to the hasMany property the way you have it. You can't get *null* then.

Comment: You do not have to save the parent before adding the children - this is one of the cooler features of GORM. Saving the outer object causes cascaded validation and saves of inner objects. RTFM.

Comment: My impressions exactly and that's why I tried the setup and had no problems myself. I was merely responding to the NPE problem reported.

Answer (score -1):

```
new DataType(
  dataTypeProps: [
    new DataTypeProp(name: 'test name1', value: 'test value1'),
    new DataTypeProp(name: 'test name2', value: 'test value2')
  ]
).save()
```